# Insert percentage of values in ggplot

Tags: r, charts, ggplot2

I'm quite new in R, but I'm trying to do a `facet_grid` using `ggplot` package in R and, for better data visualization, I'd like to insert the percentage of values in each quadrant for the column `groupings`, like the image below:

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Zt7ev.png]

Can be one or another, in each quadrant or in legend.

My code is this one below

```
ggplot(df1_final,aes(x=revenue,y=visits,col=groupings)) +
  geom_jitter(alpha=I(1/2)) + 
  xlim(c(0,20000)) + 
  facet_grid(group_lvl_1_visits ~ group_lvl_1_revenue)
```

Could anyone help me on this?

**EDIT: Both solutions helped me a lot, very good ones.**

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! [How to make a great R reproducible example?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269)

Comment: having a `dput(df1_final)` pasted in to your example would help folks help you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's one way to do it:

```
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(mpg, aes(displ, hwy)) +
  geom_point() +
  facet_wrap(~class, nrow = 4) ->
  p
p + geom_text(
  data = setNames(as.data.frame(prop.table(table(mpg$class))),c("class", "lab")),
  mapping = aes(label = scales::percent(lab)), 
  x = 4, 
  y = 40
)
```

[image]

or, for `facet_grid`:

```
p <- ggplot(mpg, aes(displ, cty)) + geom_point()
p <- p + facet_grid(drv ~ cyl)
p + geom_text(
  data = setNames(as.data.frame(prop.table(table(mpg$drv, mpg$cyl)), stringsAsFactors = F), c("drv","cyl","lab")),
  mapping = aes(label = scales::percent(lab)),
  x=4.5, 
  y=30
)
```

[image]

Comment: OP is using `facet_grid()`

Comment: super neat soln for the `facet_wrap()` use-case, tho. might want to keep it here

Answer (score 2):

Here's a tidyverse + label-in-legend solution:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)
library(scales)

group_by(mpg, cyl, drv) %>% 
  mutate(color=sprintf("%s-%s",cyl,drv)) %>% 
  ungroup(mpg) -> mpg

gg <- ggplot(mpg, aes(displ, cty))
gg <- gg + geom_point(aes(color=color))
gg <- gg + facet_grid(drv ~ cyl)

count(mpg, color) %>% 
  ungroup() %>% 
  mutate(pct=percent(n/sum(n)),
         lab=sprintf("%s (%s)", color, pct)) -> pct_df


gg <- gg + scale_color_discrete(name="Title", labels=pct_df$lab)
gg
```

[image]